# Validation error messages are not displayed in angular json schema.

Tags: material-design, angular-schema-form

I am using angular-schema-form to display my json data in UI, which works fine as expected.
https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form

I wanted a material design for my page, so I used angular-schema-form-material decorator. 
https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form-material

**Example code:** 
app.js:

```html
require("angular-schema-form")
require("angular-schema-form-material")
require('angular-messages')
require('angular-material')
require('angular-ui-ace')
require('tv4')
require('angular-material/angular-material.css')

var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  "schemaForm",'ngMessages', 'ngMaterial', 'ui.ace' ])
```

controller.js

```html
var signalSchema = { /* Actual schema definition */};
var signalForm = ['*'];
var signalData = {/* Actual json data from DB */ };
```

index.html

```html
<form name="signalsForm " layout="column" class="canOverviewSignals " sf-schema="signalSchema"
     sf-form="signalForm " sf-model="signalData" sf-options="{validateOnRender: true} ">
</form>
```

The form is rendered properly and validation messages are displayed without material decorator. But on including the decorator the validation messages are not displaying. For example when a 'required' value is not entered, the error message 'field is required' is not displayed when the decorator in included. The below error message is displayed in browser console.

[View Console error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT3d0.png)